# stack generic class not working

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java how to: Generic Array creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation)

```
import java.util.EmptyStackException;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Stack<E> extends Vector<E> {
    private E a[];
    private int top;

    public void Stack() {
        a = new E[100];
        top = -1;
    }

    public void Stack(int n) {
        a = new E[n];
        top = -1;
    }

    public E pop() {
        E obj;
        int len = size();
        if (top == -1)
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        else
            obj = a[top--];
        return obj;
    }

    public void push(E e) {
        if (e == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        else if (top == size() - 1)
            System.out.println("Stack full");
        else {
            a[++top] = e;
            System.out.println("pushed :" + e);
        }

    }

    public int size() {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; a[i] != null; i++)
            ;
        return i;
    }

}
```

This is my stack generics class in java. I am getting an error in array declaration inside the two constructor i.e Stack() and Stack(int n). The error is "generic array creation" in both cases. please help

Comment: Please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation

Comment: Your constructors are not really constructors, as constructors do not have a return type. Also, you are extending `Vector`, which means you don't need to have a local array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generic array is can not be created. so use Object array.

```
import java.io.*;
 import java.util.EmptyStackException;
 import java.util.Vector;
 public class Stack extends Vector 
 {
   private Object a[];
   private int top;
   public void Stack() 
  {
    a=new Object[100];
    top=-1;
  }
  public void Stack(int n) 
  {
    a=new Object[n];
    top=-1;
  }
  public E pop() 
  {
    E   obj;
    int len = size();
    if (top == -1)
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    else
       obj=(E) a[top--]; 
    return obj;
  }
  public void push(E e) 
  {
    if(e==null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    else if(top==size()-1)
        System.out.println("Stack full");
    else
    {
       a[++top]=e;
       System.out.println("pushed :"+e);
    }


}
public int size() 
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;a[i]!=null;i++);
    return i;
}
}
```

Comment: Generic array can certainly be created. See the other answers.. But using an `Object[]` is also ok.

Comment: what does Object[] do ? Can it store hetrogenous datas ??

Answer (score 1):

You do not have constructors in your class these are methods. for construtors remove the void type. Constructors don't have return types. Also your class name starts with lower letter stack and constructors start with Stack . Rename your class to Stack and remove void types.

You need to do it like this

```
      public  Stack(Class<E> cls) 
 {
      a = (E[]) Array.newInstance( cls);

   top=-1;
 }

public  Stack(Class<E> cls,int n) 
  {
   a = (E[]) Array.newInstance( cls,n);
    top=-1;
  }
```

see [Generic Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation)

Following is your working class with object creation in main method.

```
class Stack<E> extends Vector<E> {
    private E a[];
    private int top;

    public   Stack(Class<E> cls) 
    {


      a = (E[]) Array.newInstance( cls);

      top=-1;
    }

    public   Stack(Class<E> cls,int n) 
    {


      a = (E[]) Array.newInstance( cls,n);

      top=-1;
    }

    public E pop() {
        E obj;
        int len = size();
        if (top == -1)
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        else
            obj = a[top--];
        return obj;
    }

    public void push(E e) {
        if (e == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        else if (top == size() - 1)
            System.out.println("Stack full");
        else {
            a[++top] = e;
            System.out.println("pushed :" + e);
        }

    }

    public int size() {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; a[i] != null; i++)
            ;
        return i;
    }

  public static void main(String...strings ){
      Stack<Integer> st=new Stack<Integer>(Integer.class,n);
  }  

}
```

Comment: What will be the parameters while making the object ??

Comment: stack<String> stack=new stack<String>(String.class);

Comment: stack<Integer> st=new stack<Integer>(Integer.class,n); this is not working ???

Comment: If this ans solved ur issue then select it as the right answere.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I do not think this is a good solution. Passing the type into the constructor of a generic class (i.e. `new Stack<Integer>(Integer.class)`) is poor design.